# Javascript redirect works in chrome but not IE

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

The below JavaScript script registry works in chrome without any issue. When used with IE the URL is missing a `/`.

For example, with Chrome I correctly land on `//Sever-Name/Submit.aspx`
In IE I land on `//Sever-NameSubmit.aspx`

Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this issue

```c#
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect",
"alert('Your request Was submitted successfully. You will be redirected to the confirmation page.');
window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "Submit.aspx';", true);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing, but it seems a regular form submit with the action attribute set would do what you want without javascript ?

Comment: Seems pretty easy to understand to me. It's just Javascript that takes you to another page after an alert. Form submit doesn't include a popup box.

Comment: why must you use Request.ApplicationPath? why not just window.location='Submit.aspx';", true);  Is Submit.aspx in the same directory as the current page (NameSubmit.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
window.location='" + "/" + Request.ApplicationPath + "/" + "Submit.aspx';", true);
```

Also, in JavaScript, the "/" is used as an escape character. You may have to escape the escape charecter as well: `var link = "site.com//myPage.aspx"`

Comment: I added the "/" and that caused it to also stop working in Chrome as well as IE.